# Finding an open neighborhood in the domain of a continuous map whose image is contained in an open neighborhood in its codomain

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, continuity, proof-explanation

Let $\varphi: X \to Y$ be a continuous map between two Hausdorff topological spaces $X$ and $Y$. Let $\varphi(x) = y$ for $x \in X$, $y \in Y$ and $U$ be an open neighborhood of $y$.

**Question**: Does there exist an open neighborhood $U'$ of $x$ such that $\varphi(U') \subseteq U$?

**Motivation**: I need it for the proof that the inverse limit of Hausdorff topological spaces is a closed subspace of the underlying product space. The question above is exactly the one I have in the proof shown in *Lemma 1.1.2* in the book *Profinite Groups* by *Ribes* and *Zalesskii*, cf. [this link](https://books.google.de/books?id=K_DrCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA4&dq=profinite%20groups%20ribes%20zalesskii%20lemma%201.1.2&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4ke_smOLgAhXHCuwKHSynDxcQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=profinite%20groups%20ribes%20zalesskii%20lemma%201.1.2&f=false).

**Thoughts and Ideas**: Considering images from the Euclidean spaces, I think one must use the continuity at least one for an argument. I also thought that one could choose $U' = \varphi^{-1}(U)$ which should be open (since $\varphi$ is continuous) and $x \in U'$ (by definition of the inverse image). I thought that this argument should be correct, but I was wondering why Ribes/Zalesskii made it so complicated then.

Could you please verify my line of reasoning? Thank you!

Comment: Your line of reasoning looks correct, but I don't see what it has to do with that lemma?

Comment: @Billy: In the proof of this Lemma by Ribes/Zalesskii (cf. link) one chooses an open neighborhood $U'$ to have this property.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. They spend one sentence defining $U'$ - that sentence beginning partway through line 1 of page 4 - and your line of reasoning here correctly explains why defining $U'$ as in that sentence is possible. The rest of the proof is about something else. They don't just want an open neighbourhood of $x_r$ (which is not an element of either of the spaces of interest, $\prod X_i$ or $\lim X_i$); they want an open neighbourhood of $(x_i)$ (which *is* an element of $\prod X_i$) that doesn't intersect $\lim X_i$.

Comment: Yes. This is also equivalent to continuity. There are many useful consequences of continuity which  are also equivalent to continuity. E.g. (i). Inverses of closed sets are closed. (ii). $ \forall  C\subset A\,(\;f(Cl_A(C))\subset Cl_B(f(C)\;).$  Number (ii) is the topological generality of "$f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ is continuous iff  $(f(x_n))_n$ converges to $f(x)$ whenever $(x_n)_n$ converges to $x$".

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes.
That is a direct result of the theorem
f:X -> Y is continuous at a iff
for all open V nhood f(a), exists open U nhood x with f(U) subset V.